# Create new column with geodesic distances

Tags: r, haversine

How can I add a new column to my dataframe that includes the geodesic distance of every observation? The rows in my dataframe are observations of cars that are hired and include the starting points (longitude + latitude) and end points of the trip (longitude + latitude).

The geodesic distance is calculated with the following R function:

```
haversine<- function(long1, lat1, long2, lat2) {

  stopifnot(is.numeric(long1),
            is.numeric(lat1),
            is.numeric(long2),
            is.numeric(lat2),
            long1 > -180,
            long1 < 180,
            lat1 > -180,
            lat1 < 180,
            long2 > -180,
            long2 < 180,
            lat2 > -180,
            lat2 < 180  
    )

  long1 <- long1*pi/180
  lat1 <- lat1*pi/180
  long2 <- long2*pi/180
  lat2 <- lat2*pi/180

  R <- 6371 # Earth mean radius [km]
  delta.long <- (long2 - long1)
  delta.lat <- (lat2 - lat1)
  a <- sin(delta.lat/2)^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(delta.long/2)^2
  c <- 2 * asin(min(1,sqrt(a)))
  d = R * c
  return(d) # Distance in km
}
```

With this formula the distance can be calculated:

```
distance <- haversine(longitude1,latitude1,longitude2,latitude2)
```

Since my dataframe includes more than 100,000 observations, I would like to add a column to my dataframe which includes all the geodesic distances of the car trips.

I tried: 
`df["GeoDist"] <- haversine(LongitudeStart, LatitudeStart, LongitudeEnd, LatitudeEnd)`

This resulted in an extra column, however all the distances are zero in this colum. These distances are not zero when I calculate them manually with the previous formula.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `distHaversine()`, from the **geosphere** package. Or, for more accurate results, use `distVincentyEllipsoid()`. (Both functions take coordinates in degrees and return distances in meters.)

```
## Example data representing voyages of 1 and 2 degrees directly north from equator.
df <- data.frame(x_begin = c(0,0), y_begin = c(0,0), 
                 x_end   = c(0,0), y_end   = c(1,2))

library(geosphere)
distHaversine(df[, 1:2],  df[, 3:4])        ## Assumes a spherical Earth
# [1] 111319.5 222639.0
distVincentyEllipsoid(df[,1:2],  df[,3:4])  ## Much more accurate*
## [1] 110574.4 221149.5

## * According to Wikipedia, 1 degree of latitude at equator == 110.574 km 
## (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_longitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `mapply` because you are passing vector arguments.

```
# reproducible example
# 38.8895° N,  77.0352° W  # 
# 47.6204° N, 122.3491° W  # washington monument to space needle
# 40.6892° N,  74.0444° W  # 
# 37.8197° N, 122.4786° W  # statue of liberty to golden gate bridge
df <- data.frame(y1=c(  38.8895,  40.6892),
                 x1=c( -77.0352, -74.0444),
                 y2=c(  47.6204, 37.8197 ),
                 x2=c( -122.3491,-122.4786 ))

with(df, mapply(haversine, lat1=y1, long1=x1, lat2=y2, long2=x2) )
# [1] 3738.587 4129.629 # looks right to me
```